# Cycles CPU rendering - running out of memory - why?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, shaders

I'm rendering a huge scene on CPU. I have 32 gb of RAM, and 45 GB on my SSD where temp files is stored.

I get "Out of memory" error when i trying to render the scene. "Mem" usage (at the top of rendering window) say it peaks at only 7.9 GB.

Why it may be happening?

Comment: Have you tried prioritizing blender in task manager? (Or the mac equivalent)?

Comment: This might be a bug due to an older version of blender.
I encountered a similar problem when rendering a grass field in 2.78a
But when I opened my scene and resaved it in 2.78c everything worked as it should. Resaving was mandatory because rerendering the 2.78a blendfile in 2.78c was reproducing the CUDA error.